# how to open files using intent action with latest Android storage framework?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-storage

Since Android introduced major changes in storage framework recently much of the documentation talks about permissions and scoped storage. But I couldn't find details on how to process Uri of a file, for it to be readable by other apps.

The intent action to view/read a file by other apps fail. I don't understand what's the problem here;

1. Does it have to do with [difference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File) between `java.io.File` and `java.nio.File`?
2. The Uri has missing permissions or the Uri is not well formatted.

The Android [storage samples](https://github.com/android/storage-samples) (FileManager) has this bug as well. It lists all the files in a directory successfully but can't open a selected image, or a document. I've [reported this issue](https://github.com/android/storage-samples/issues/61) but no help so far.

Following snippet is from FileManager (storage-samples)

```
fun openFile(activity: AppCompatActivity, selectedItem: File) {
    // Get URI and MIME type of file
    val uri = Uri.fromFile(selectedItem).normalizeScheme()
    val mime: String = getMimeType(uri.toString())

    // Open file with user selected app
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    intent.data = uri
    intent.type = mime
    return activity.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: `Uri.fromFile(selectedItem)` And you think you can inform us without telling the value for selectedItem.        `FileUriExposedException`. And nothing has changed for ACTION_VIEW for Android 11.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "process Uri". If you want to start an activity to view some file for which you have read access, use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to use with `ACTION_VIEW`. See [this code snippet](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/v1.9/PdfProvider/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/pdfprovider/MainActivity.kt#L51-66), for example. Note that this is not new to Android 11.

Comment: Did you find the answer ? If yes, please share it.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy Yes I posted the answer here check it out. I also made changes to SDK Storage samples this issue has been rectified there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the hints from the comments, I found the answer in [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Building).

> Caution: If you want to set both the URI and MIME type, don't call *setData()* and *setType()* because they each nullify the value of the other. Always use **setDataAndType()** to set both URI and MIME type.

The reason behind `openFile` didn't throw `FileUriExposedException` in **android-storage-samples** is that after setting `intent.type`, the Uri gets nullified and when I changed it to `setDataAndType()` I got the exception. The final snippet looks like

```
fun openFile(activity: AppCompatActivity, selectedItem: File) {
// Get URI and MIME type of file
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity.applicationContext, AUTHORITY, selectedItem)
//    val uri = Uri.fromFile(selectedItem).normalizeScheme()
val mime: String = getMimeType(uri.toString())

// Open file with user selected app
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
//    intent.data = uri
//    intent.type = mime
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime)
    return activity.startActivity(intent)
}
```

I think they forgot to update the samples over time, let me create a pull request to commit this change over there as well.